# elasticsearch sort by document id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a simple index in elasticsearch and all my ids are manually added, i.e. I do not add documents with automatic string ids.

Now the requirement is to get list of all documents page by page and sorted by the document id (i.e. _id)

When I tried this with _id, it did not work. Then I looked for it on forums and found out this much that I have to use _uid for that. This actually works, although I have no clue how. But another problem is that the sorting is done as if the the _id is string. And it actually is a string. But I want the results as if the _id was a number.

So there are two issues here:

1. Why sorting does not work with _id and it does work with _uid
2. Is there a way to get document ids sorted as numbers and not integers

For e.g. if my doc ids are `1`, `2`, `3`, ..... , `55`

I am getting results in this order:

`1`, `10`, `11`, `12`, ... , `19`, `2`, `20`, ... so on

While I would like to get the results in this order:

`1`, `2`, `3`, ... so on

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the `_id` indexed:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "some_type": {
      "_id": {
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use a script:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "doc['_id'].value?.isInteger()?doc['_id'].value.toFloat():null",
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Even though I strongly recommend, if possible, changing the id to `integer` rather having it as `string` and contain numbers, instead.

And I kind of doubt that it worked with `_uid` because `_uid` is a combination between type and id.

Comment: So this means the only solution is to have the actual document id within the document it self right? If this is so, then I would prefer having the id field created as an integer. I was just hoping that there is some way to do it without requiring the id copied inside the document.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post: the id needs to be indexed, not stored. And it doesn't matter if the id is string or not, you still need to index it. I was saying it's better to be `integer` rather than `string` because you will not need `script`s to do the sorting. `script`s are less performant.

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons the code above didn't work for me. ("dynamic method [java.lang.String, isInteger/0] not found")
However the script below works (only if your _id can be converted into integers)

```
GET ENDPOINT/INDEX/_search
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": "return Integer.parseInt(doc['_id'].value)",
      "order": "desc" // I personally needed descending
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id`, I used `id.keyword` and it worked.. sample code below:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id.keyword": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This only worked because your index mapping contains an field named "id", this wouldn't work in a index mapping where you don't have this field